# SF Movie containing a psychic girl, a time capsule that is unearthed (or buried?) and lots of numbers

Tags: story-identification, movie

The movie was released probably in the latter half of the 2000-2010 period. There is a time capsule that is shown to have been buried earlier and is then unearthed (*although I'm not sure of the unearthing part*). There is an adolescent girl who encounters a huge set of numbers that mean gibberish to everyone except her and she starts screaming that people are going to die.

NOTE: I don't have a detailed recollection of that movie.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is the 2009 film *Knowing*, starring Nicolas Cage.

The time capsule was buried in 1959, and contains students' drawings of what the future will look like in fifty years' time. One student, a girl named Lucinda, fills her page with a seemingly nonsensical string of random numbers. When the capsule is opened in 2009, Lucinda's sheet is given to a current pupil at the school, whose father (played by Cage) realises it encodes the dates, locations, and death tolls of every major tragedy within the past fifty years - and some that have not yet occurred.

(Note: I started typing this answer before Martin posted his, and I'm posting it anyway as it's more complete.)

Comment: This is indeed the correct movie.Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's "Knowing" (2009) directed by Alex Proyas and starring Nicholas Cage.

Comment: One-liner answers aren't very useful.  You could improve this by explaining why you think this movie matches the question.